# Converting air compressor to gas but leaving ac motor on

Tags: power-electronics, electromagnetism, electro-mechanical

I have a compressor with the crankshaft being the the front part of the shaft of an A/C motor's armature.. The rear of the AC motor's armature has enough protruding shaft to put a pulley on it and hook a 5hp engine to it via a belt pully system... Do I need to remove the windings from the armature so it does not create some type of EMF drag ?? I dont think there are magnets in the motor.

Comment: This may be a better question on https://engineering.stackexchange.com, because you not only need to be concerned with electromagnetic drag, but also whether the bearings will stand up to the side load presented by a belt.

Comment: If you can, _edit your question_ with a picture of the motor.  Unless the whole assembly was designed to be compact and cheap, there's a good chance that there's a removable mechanical coupling of some sort between the motor and the compressor crankshaft -- you may want to take a closer look and tell us why you don't believe that's the case.

Comment: I was thinking i might use engine in-line to avoid side bearing load but realized the rotation would be incorrect.. obviously i ,and anyone else on this site, will nit know what the bearings specs are for the motor and therefore could not give me correct information.. So, on that note, does using a belt tensioner , other than obvious reasons, help alleviate some side.loadiing ? - Cus i will need to use a pulley system...

Comment: Questions about transferring the _mechanical_ power is definitely a question for https://engineering.stackexchange.com.  A belt tension won't help with the side load of a properly-loaded belt -- but it may make it easier to achieve proper belt loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem with electromagnetic drag as long as the windings are disconnected from external cables, capacitors, etc. and stay that way.

It is required that the electric motor works correctly right now - i.e. there shouldn't be a problem with bearings, burned-out windings, shorted turns, etc. Only then it can be left in-system. Otherwise, if it's damaged, it has to be removed. Most any condition that won't let the motor operate when powered up is enough to make it drag or cause further damage when backdriven.

Comment: Thank you for responding.. the motor works fine but it does look to have a start capacitor.. Should i disconnect that ? As far as side load on bearings, I will be able to cituate the engine shaft in line with armature shaft and use rubber ring type coupler..

Comment: Yes, remove the start capacitor and your other precautions are good as well.

Comment: Thx everyone, you gents are awesome.. appreciate the help. I will commence with retrofit.. 